# iOS origin? margin? error on iPad and iPhone 6+ with autolayout

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, autolayout, iphone-6-plus

I had this issue for a log time in different apps and I dont know exactly whats wrong.

I've started a new app, 1 page, the first view controller, painted the background pink. Added a view to cover all the root view with green.

[image: Xcode]

This works properly in iPhone 5/iPhone 6

[image: iPhone 5]

But on iPhone 6+ I get a margin to the right and another to the left (so the view doesn't cover the root view)

[image: iPhone 6+]

And the same issue happens with the iPad (retina or not)

[image: iPad 2]

Any help on why this is happening is very much appreciated!

My regards to you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Added a view to cover all the root view with green.

But you pinned it, with your constraints, to the root view's *margins*. Instead, pin it (with zero constant values) to the root view's *edges*.

Comment: can you elaborate, or add an image of how this is done?

Comment: Follow the link I gave you.

Comment: Thanks @matt thats what I've been looking, it seams no one has a post about this for iphone 6+